# An error occurred while preparing the query

Tags: sql, excel, oledb, linked-server

An error occurred while preparing the query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(UGB,1,9) as EntityCode, SUBSTRING(FUNCIONARIO/CREDOR DESCONTADO,1,9) as NRCId, SUBSTRING(FUNCIONARIO/CREDOR DESCONTADO,11,75) as CustName, VALOR as ReceiptAmount FROM [SubmissionDetails$]
```

for execution against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

to read these data from excel

Comment: when fields have special characters of spaces use [ ] `[FUNCIONARIO/CREDOR DESCONTADO]`

Answer (score 0):

The FUNCIONARIO/CREDOR contains a special character(/), so I would suggest you use square brackets.

Comment: An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT SUBSTRING(UGB,1,9) as EntityCode, SUBSTRING([FUNCIONARIO_CREDOR DESCONTADO,1,9]) as NRCId, SUBSTRING([FUNCIONARIO_CREDOR DESCONTADO,11,100]) as CustName, VALOR as ReceiptAmount FROM [SubmissionDetails$]" for execution against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".    STILL SHOWING SAME ERROR

Comment: @SugiJoshuva post the call stack from the error. and from inner exception if there is one.
And not in comment, but edit your question